# How can I get the data from an ArrayList that store another array inside of that ArrayList (Java)?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have an ArrayList and this ArrayList have other array inside, I need to obtain the data inside this other array.

[This is the structure of the ArrayList and the data inside, I need to get that data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxKjJ.png)

This is the code that I use for get all the ArrayList but I need to get the other array that is store in the index(0) and when I can get this data I need to store it in an new Array

```
 if (msg.equals("warning")) {
    ArrayList<String> dataWarn = (ArrayList<String>) data;

    Log.i("api", dataWarn.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the inner ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> innerList = data.get(0);
```

Then you can extract the data inside:

```
String value = innerList.get(0);
```

And add it to some `otherList`:

```
List<String> otherList = Arrays.asList(value);
```

Comment: Yep, your answer is the right way to extract the data, thank you my friend.

Comment: @AlanMuñoz Yey! Please consider accepting an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
String[] newArray = new String[outerArray.size()];
for(int i = 0; i<outerArray.size();i++){
   newArray[i]=outerArray.get(0).get(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it was very useful too